# Past null horizon

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

What are past null horizons and future null horizons? Are they the same as past event horizons and future event horizons? The literature on Black Holes often uses these terms but I don’t get it. Please give a definition and then define some math.

[image]

Comment: A Google search for “past null horizon” gives only a half a dozen results. So this is not a term used conventionally. Are you sure you are not confusing it with “past null infinity”?

Comment: No. It is not past null infinity. I saw this "past null horizon" term in Penrose process, holography principle or Kerr Black holes etc

Comment: Can you provide these links?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/92335/Desktop/Amsterdam%20thesis.pdf

Comment: This is a link to your personal computer not accessible by others.

Comment: Look at the post. I've attached an image

Comment: Can you post the title and author’s name?

Comment: It is a Master's thesis for University of Amsterdam. "Black holes Branes, Fluids and entropy" by Ian Nagle